# Examples of excess intersection theory?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, vector-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold of dimension $m$ and $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ a vector bundle of rank $e$. Given a section $s$ of the bundle $\pi:E\rightarrow M$, we expect that the zero locus $Z(s)$ of $s$ is a submanifold $N\subset M$ of dimension $m-e$. This is true if $s$ can be perturbed into a general position so that $s(M)$ and the zero section intersect transversally.

Perturbation is not always possible (for example in holomorphic category category). In this case we need "excess intersection theory"; if the section $s$ lies in a subbundle $F\subset E$ and is a transversal section of $F$, the correct $(m-e)$-cycle we should take is the Euler class of the quotient bundle $E/F$, which is homologous to $Z(s)$ if transverse perturbation of $s$ exists.

My problem is that I don't really know good explicit examples with which I can compute things. Could anyone give me an example or reference, which shows how useful excess intersection theory is?

**Edit**
My motivation to study excess intersection theory is virtual cycles of moduli spaces, which of course are very good examples of excess intersection theory. But I am looking for some elementary examples on which I can compute things. I want to convince myself that the theory is really reasonable by computing a few simple examples.

Comment: Have a look at chap. VI, par. 1 of the book "Riemann-Roch algebra" By Fulton-Lang.

Answer (score 8):

A good example might be the *self-intersection* of a submanifold $A\subset M$. We would like this to be the intersection of $A$ with a perturbation $A'\subset M$ such that the intersection is transverse. However once we start perturbing things, we lose control, so its better to notice that $A$ intersects itself *cleanly* (in the terminology of Bott and Quillen) and use the excess intersection formula.

In the setup you give, the bundle $\pi\colon E\to M$ is the tangent bundle of $M$, whose total space we can identify with an open neighbourhood of the diagonal $M\subset M\times M$. The section $s\colon M\to E$ is given by the diagonal embedding. The excess bundle $E/F$ is therefore identified with the normal bundle of $A$ in $M$. In this case, then, the excess intersection formula gives that the self-intersection of $i\colon A\subset M$ is given by the push-forward of the Euler class of its normal bundle, $i_!e(\nu_i)$.

This is of course a very basic example of the excess intersection formula. You'll find more in-depth Algebraic Geometry applications in the book "Intersection Theory" by William Fulton (see in particular chapters 6 and 9). In the topological setting, Quillen used excess intersections in his seminal work on cobordism theory ("Elementary proofs of some results in cobordism theory using Steenrod operations", Adv. Math. 7 1971 29–56 (1971)).

Answer (score 3):

Surely not the simplest example but certainly one of the reason why excess intersection theory is useful is the theory of virtual fundamental classes. Suppose that A is some moduli space and that you
can find M,E, s as in the question such that A = Z(s). E/F is called the obstruction bundle (it is the obstruction to the transversality of s). Then the pullback to A of the Poincare dual of
the top chern class of the obstruction bundle is an homology class of the "expected " dimension m-e.
In order to simplify suppose that this dimension is 0 then the integral of 1 over the virtual fundamental class has to be interpreted as the number of elements in A for a generic perturbation
of the parameters of which M can depend, even if such a deformation actually does not exist.

In general, there does not exist M,E and s but sometimes it exists locally and one can still use excess intersection theory in order to define a virtual fundamental class.
Most of the  counting theories of curves uses this idea (Gromov-Witten, Donaldaon-Thoms, stables pairs ...)(see for example for a survey "13/2 ways to count curves" of R.Pandharipande and R.P.Thomas).

In this way, one obtains a lot of examples which can be seen as application of excess intersection theory : when A is smooth, the obstruction is really a bundle and you just have to calculate a top chern class (just to cite a real "concrete" simple example : Gromov-Witten invariants for homology class 0 can be written has an integral of caracteristic classes over the moduli space of curves.
There are surely thousands of such examples.)

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the virtual cycles of moduli space. In fact they are my motivation to study excess intersection theory. I should have emphasized that I am looking for an elementary exam on which I can compute things. 